In how many ways can an $m\times n$ grid be coloured?
We colour each cell of an $m\times n$ grid by using one of $k$ colours. The cells are coloured such that no two adjacent cells are the same colour. In how many ways can this be done?
The $1\times n$ case is simple. There are $k$ choices for the first cell, $k-1$ for the second cell, and $k-1$ for each next cell. Hence in total, there are $k(k-1)^{n-1}$ ways to do this.
The $2\times n$ case was solved here. It's slightly more complicated but still straightforward. There are $k(k-1)$ ways to colour the first column. For each next column, there are $(k-1)^2$ ways to choose a pair of cells such that they don't conflict with the previous column, with $k-2$ of those pairs having the same colour. Hence there are $(k-1)^2-(k-2)=k^2-3k+3$ ways to choose cells for the next column. In total, there are $k(k-1)(k^2-3k+3)^{n-1}$ ways to colour the whole grid.
I've attempted the $3\times n$ case with no success. If we try a similar method to the previous case, we have $k(k-1)^2$ possible ways to colour the first column. The number of possible ways to colour the second column then seems to depend on the specific colouring of the first column. For example, with $k=3$ (having colours red, green and blue,)
R _ _ _ _
G _ _ _ _
B _ _ _ _

there are $4$ ways to colour the second column (G R G, G B R, G B G, B R G.) On the other hand, if we colour the first row in this way:
R _ _ _ _
G _ _ _ _
R _ _ _ _

there are $5$ ways to colour the second column (G R G, G R B, G B G, B R G, B R B.) It seems that this approach doesn't work.
Any idea how we can solve $3\times n$ and the general case?

This is called the chromatic polynomial.  Googling for 'chromatic polynomial of grid graph' brings me to this old post. Apparently there is no known formula in general, although I believe the generating function for the polynomials for the $3\times n$ case can be found (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.6206).
